# How can I use next.js image and attach it to the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm unable to create a fixed background image (parallex effect) using Tailwind CSS + Next.js Image.

You can see it in action on [this Template Monster theme](https://www.templatemonsterpreview.com/demo/187467.html).

This is the code I have tried:

```
<section className="stats w-full h-48 relative">
  <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 object-cover bg-cover">
    <Image
      layout='fill'
      src={data.backgroundImageUrl}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="relative z-10 flex flex-col items-center">
    <div>Stat 1</div>
    <div>Stat 2</div>
    <div>Stat 3</div>
    <div>Stat 4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And it does not work. The image attaches to the section and there is no parallax effect.

I can replace it with:

```
  <div className="aboslute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 object-cover bg-cover"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${data.backgroundImageUrl})`
    }}
  />
```

And it works. But then it does not optimize the image and my SEO score drops in lighthouse.

How can I use `next/image` alongside TailwindCSS for parallax effect of section backgrounds?

Comment: In next.js fill layout is usually paired with objectFit property, so you don't need object-cover and bg-cover classes. In next.js image component is not background, but image itself. So it must be with position: fixed similar to background-attachment: fixed. You can apply it to image wrapper.

Comment: @Taras, I'm unable to make it work. Can you send your comment as an asnwer with code involved. And if you can create a code sandbox, I would really appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: For me, it attaches to the entire document. I want it to only attach to the background of that specific section. In fact it's apparent as the fixed background for all other sections too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-aye7nj?file=pages%2Findex.js
Create wrapper with clipPath property and wrapper with fixed position.

```
<div
  style={{
    position: 'relative',
    height: '60vh',
    width: '100%',
    clipPath: 'inset(0 0 0 0)',
  }}
>
  <div
    style={{
      position: 'fixed',
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      left: '0',
      top: '0',
    }}
  >
    <Image
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630496128261-27ce4ab6ad76?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80"
      layout="fill"
      objectFit="cover"
      sizes="100vw"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. That `clipPath` was the missing piece.